# Putting div on the left of a 100% width table with the same height

Tags: html, css, height

I want to put a radio button (or any other element) on the left of my tables, but have the button be vertically centered.  If I new that the tables were all going to be the same size I could use relative positioning. However, I do not know this. [This jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x34nc/) is close to what I need, however, the left div needs be be of the same height (for vertical alignment) and it also needs to reside in the margin. This [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x34nc/1/) is closer to what I am looking for, but seems a little hacky and doesn't allow for tables of different heights.  Can I accomplish this using HTML/CSS without javascript?

Here's the HTML I'm looking at using to accomplish this:

```
<div class="item">
    <div class="one"><input type="radio" name="group"/></div>
    <div class="two">
    <table>
        <tr><td>Data</td><td>More Data</td></tr>
        <tr><td>another</td><td>row</td></tr>
        <tr><td>of ...</td><td>you guessed it</td></tr>
        <tr><td>just</td><td>more data</td></tr>
    </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

and CSS:

```
table {border-collapse:collapse;width:100%;}
td {border:1px solid black;padding:10px;}
.item {margin:10px; padding:10px; background:red;}
.two {background:blue;}

/* customization */
.one {background:yellow;text-align:center;width:20px;display:table-cell;vertical-align:middle;}
.two {margin-left:20px;}

/* hacky */
.one {height:50px;position:relative;top:55px;}
.two {margin-top:-50px;}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vertical align only works inside table cells or between inline elements. So either use a table with one row and two cells, for `.one` and `.two` or use CSS to convert the div's into table cells:

```
.one, .two {display:table-cell;}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/x34nc/2/)** *(Only tested in firefox, don't have other browsers installed, hope it works)*

Comment: You can add display: table-row to .item, but then again you'll lose the padding. You could add padding with border spacing, but then there will be space between .one and .two. What I recommand is to stop with these display stuff, and use proper HTML mark-up: use table where a table is needed.

Comment: I know, nested tables are nasty (pun intended), but either way, you are using tables, only now you have a shorter yet harder to read mark-up (harder, because half of the notation is hidden in the CSS).

Comment: I believe you are saying that the working solution because it uses `display:table-row;` is not the best method as it is not proper HTML mark-up. If this is true, then what would  be the proper HTML markup to accomplish this task?

Comment: using a html tr instead of a div, which acts as a table-row